# Running Typescript from Launchd

Tags: macos, npx, launchd

**Updated**; I found the path to npx using `type npx`

I would like to run a TypeScript script from a launchd.

I'm successfully running the script directly using `/usr/local/bin/npx ts-node /path/to/script.ts`

However I can't figure out how to code this into the plist file.  I have:

```xml
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/npx</string>
        <string>ts-node</string>
        <string>/path/to/script.ts</string>
    </array>
```

But this exits with code 127 and logs the error `env: node: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding `PATH` environment variable to the plist file:

```xml
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
           <key>PATH</key>
           <string>/usr/local/bin:/bin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/npx</string>
        <string>ts-node</string>
        <string>/path/to/script.ts</string>
    </array>
```